# Backbone do CRUD operations on child from parent view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

Im newbie to Backbone. I have a main view which has only tabs. I want to do CRUD operations from this main view - i have CRUD buttons in the main view itself. Each tabs content is child for main view. So how can i get a reference to a particular tabs model or view in the parent/main view. Plz give some example

Answer (score 0):

The  main view and tabs (sub-views) are of your own design. So, how to get to the sub-views should be in your code as when you creating objects.  It is not really a backbone question.

If you want to have a more structural way of using backbone, you can take a look [backbone.marionette](http://marionettejs.com/)

There are plenty of documentation can be found in [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/master/docs).

You can also take a look at [this example](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette), it uses backbone/backbone.marionette/JQM.